# Python Pandas DataFrame Merge: Strange Sort Order for How = Inner

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I do not understand the sort order for Python Pandas DataFrame `merge` function with `how="inner"`. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': (6, 7, 8, 6), 'b': ("w", "x", "y", "z")})
print(df2)
print("left:")
dfMerge2 = pd.merge(df2, df2, on='a', how="left")
print(dfMerge2)
dfMerge = pd.merge(df2, df2, on='a', how="inner")
print("inner:")
print(dfMerge)
```

Result:

```
   a  b
0  6  w
1  7  x
2  8  y
3  6  z
left:
   a b_x b_y
0  6   w   w
1  6   w   z
2  7   x   x
3  8   y   y
4  6   z   w
5  6   z   z
inner:
   a b_x b_y
0  6   w   w
1  6   w   z
2  6   z   w
3  6   z   z
4  7   x   x
5  8   y   y
```

I would expect that for `how="inner"` the order of the resulting rows with

`6   z   w` and

`6   z   z`

would be the same as with `how="left"`, as the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html says:

- left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; ***preserve key order***
- inner: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; ***preserve the order of the left keys***

Comment: There is problem with duplicted `6` values, so instead `inner` join do `cross join` - all combinations of dupes values.

Comment: And in docs all values are unique, so there it working nice.

Comment: 1) I am very curious about your `cross join` code. Please post it here. Where did you find it in the pandas documentation? 2) Inner joins can have duplicate values. This is totally ok

Comment: see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18776